# how remove null result after UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Suppose to have a union, I have query a and query b

```
query A....

UNION

select (case when address is null then address else null end)......
```

the query works correctly but there is only a problem.

when case `address!=null` I read in the result null row:

```
address(column)
london square 3
new york 2
null
```

There is some way that when I do union null value are not returned? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use your `UNION` query as a *subquery* and return rows that aren't null.

```
select address
from (-- this is your current query
      select address from some_table
      union
      select address from some_other_table
     )
where address is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```sql
select (case when address is null then address else null end) ...
```

Then:

- if `address` is `NULL` then the `THEN` clause will be returned which is the `NULL` value in the `address` column; and
- if `address` is not `NULL` then the `ELSE` clause will be returned which is a `NULL` value.

So you will **ALWAYS** be returning `NULL`.

You could simplify your query to:

```sql
SELECT NULL ...
```

If you want to return a non-`NULL` value then swap the terms in the `CASE`:

```sql
select case when address is null then null else address end ...
```

However, that can just be simplified to:

```sql
select address ...
```

---

I assume you are wanting a `WHERE` clause:

```sql
UNION
SELECT address
FROM   table_name
WHERE  address IS NOT NULL;
```

However, without a complete example it is difficult to determine what your exact goal is.